# I want to use wordpress themes and plugin to develop website

Tags: plugins, themes, copyright

I want to develop website. Using wordpress. But i've one question. If i use wordpress themes and plugins. Is there will be any issue regarding copyrights of that theme or plugins. I'll use free themes. Not premium

Comment: Plugins and themes in repo of WP.org is under GPL license. You can use it, no problem :-)

Comment: Thanks. But there can be issues by plugin developers when website becomes popular. So i was just making it sure.

Comment: This link may help: https://wordpress.org/about/license/

Answer (score 1):

We can't provide legal advice here, however publicly distributed themes and plugins should be GPL or GPL compatible, so long as you don't violate the GPL you should be safe.

A good measure of wether a license is compatible with the GPL or not, is if it adds restrictions. If you can do it under the GPL, but not under the license, then that license is not GPL compatible.

As a side note, the branding of a plugin does not have to be GPL. If you buy gravity forms and resell it, you won't be violating the GPL, but you will be using their logos and marketing material ( which they will be very unhappy about, and will probably send lawyers to remind you )

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But GPL will be when i use premium themes.paid . But i'll use free themes.Wordpress is open source . so i guess i can use free themes and plugins in my website . so is it right ?

Comment: When you pay for something that's licensed under GPL, you're not paying for ownership, you're paying for distribution. Once it's in your hands you can do what you like with it. For free themes and plugins, yes you can use them in your WordPress site. I would mention though, be wary of free themes that aren't on the wordpress.org or available via the admin dashboard installer, they sometimes come with things 'hidden' in them that aren't so nice

Answer (score 0):

Simply put in *every* case this depends on terms and license of *specific* extension.

While commonly WordPress themes (more so free ones) are distributed under open source licenses this is complicated topic.

If you need high level of confidence — you'll have to hire a lawyer with relevant expertise to check situation with specific themes and plugins you intend to use.